# Can't install Firebase Performance Monitoring SDK on Android

Tags: firebase, firebase-performance

I have done all the necessary steps mentioned here https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/get-started-android and after that when i try to build the project it gives me this error

```
FirebasePerformancePlugin may only be applied to Android projects
```

Comment: Hi 1HaKr. Could you be more specific with the steps you've taken? :) We're you able to reach step 8? What version of Android Studio are you using? Is this a simple empty app? Any additional details would help. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the error it looks like the "apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'" has been added to project's build.gradle. It needs to go in the app's build.gradle, just after the "apply plugin: 'com.android.application'" line

Answer (score 0):

Can you take a look at [Performance Monitoring Android code sample on GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/perf)?

Relevant build.gradle files:

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/perf/build.gradle
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/perf/app/build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I found while implementing it.

If you are using Android studio 3.0 it has changed its syntax for including dependencies, So previously we are including library dependency using `compile` keyword and It has replaced with `implementation`.

Now If you are using Firebase plugin version less than **1.1.3** in your project level build.gradle

```
classpath "com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.2"
```

And in App level build

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:11.4.2'
```

If you have done this then it will give you error saying

> To use the Firebase Performance Plugin, the Firebase Performance Monitoring SDK must be added to the app's build.gradle. Please add compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:VERSION_NUMBER_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO_11.0.4' to the app's build.gradle.

As below Firebase plugin version, **1.1.3** Firebase is specifically looking for `compile` keyword at the app level build.gradle.

You can solve this problem 2 ways.

1> Change the word `implementation` to `compile`.

2> Upgrade your firebase plugin to `1.1.3` or later.

Hopefully, this will also be helpful to someone. :)

Answer (score 0):

In the event someone places the `apply plugin:'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'` before (or above) the default `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` within the app-level build.gralde, gradle will throw the same error message. So it is important to keep the order as documented.